# android EditText not automatically wrapping text

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

I have looked all over the place and there are a ton of similar questions on this site, but I haven't found one that works and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. I have an EditText that I have to add programatically, it typically has only one line of text but I need it to wrap if the text is longer than the width of the view.

the only xml i am using is for the table layout the edit text is eventually added to

```
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/LineItemLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
 android:stretchColumns="4"
 >

</TableLayout>
```

The edit text is the one in the 4th column but even when I removed the stretchColumns attribute it still wasn't working. (i was thinking maybe the stretching column was messing up the width and it couldn't calculate when to wrap)

Here is the code that gets looped through for each row I add to the table, p is the EditText I cant get working properly. just a bit of explanation, the row contains an EditText for a number (this one is fine, i do not want it multiline), then two Buttons and a TextView, and then the last item is the EditText that stretches the rest of the width and should be wrapping text. i put them all here in case they are causing problems because at this point i have no idea what to try next.

```
final TableRow l = new TableRow(EnvelopeModify.this);

TextView t = new TextView(EnvelopeModify.this);

t.setText("$" + lineItems.get(x).getTotal() + ", " + lineItems.get(x).getQuantity() + " " + lineItems.get(x).getItemUnits() + "");
t.setPadding(5, 5, 30, 5);

EditText p = new EditText(EnvelopeModify.this);
p.setText(lineItems.get(x).getProposalDesc());
p.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
p.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blueEditText);
p.setMinLines(1);
p.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
p.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
//TableLayout.LayoutParams tempParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
//p.setLayoutParams(tempParams);

EditText o = new EditText(EnvelopeModify.this);
o.setText(lineItems.get(x)._order);
o.setWidth(50);
o.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Button d = new Button(EnvelopeModify.this);
d.setText("Remove");
Button e = new Button(EnvelopeModify.this);
e.setText("Edit");

l.addView(o);
l.addView(d);
l.addView(e);
l.addView(t);
l.addView(p);
lineItemLayouts.add(l); // this is the tableLayout in the xml above
```

supposedly setHorizontallyScrolling(false) will allow wrapping but adding that just made things worse. Not only does the text not wrap, but the text that should be wrapping is not visible because the edittext is only showing the first part of the text (not scrolling). I can still hit enter and a new line will be created as expected but I cannot get any text to wrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the TableLayout that the EditText is in. The EditText is in the stretchable column, setting the column to also be shrinkable fixed the issue. Here is the change I made to the xml layout.

```
<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/LineItemLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
  android:stretchColumns="4"
  android:shrinkColumns="4"
  >
```

And here is what I have in the coding side that ended up working for me:

```
EditText p = new EditText(EnvelopeModify.this);
p.setText(lineItems.get(x).getProposalDesc());
p.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
p.setBackgroundResource(R.color.usedOnProposal);
p.setMinLines(1);
```

Comment: Problem fixed when I add android:shrinkColumns

Answer (score 0):

You're disabling horizontal scrolling in this line.-

```
p.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

As for the multiline issue, you could try.-

```
p.setSingleLine(false);
p.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

Comment: This is not working either, are there things I have to get rid of? I knew p.setHorizontallyScrolling(false) stopped the scrolling but from what I read in other places it was supposed to force it to wrap also. I just got rid of it and the text is not scrolling, which is weird because it was before I added it.

Comment: mmh weird indeed.  could you Try setting layout_width to match_parent?

Comment: If I set the EditText width to match_parent it doesn't show up on the screen. I used the code that is commented out above and tried with both TableLayout.LayoutParams and ViewGroup.LayoutParams (the table layout was what i was using before because i wanted to set the weight).

Comment: OK I found it, I also set the column to shrinkable and that worked. Im guessing it was stretching all the text but not the actual text box, idk but thanks for your help. If you want to edit your answer I'll accept it otherwise I'll just answer it later.

Comment: Glad you found out :) As for me, it's ok if you answer yourself (you found the answer after all), but thanks anyway.